# How can I stop C rounding the result of an operation(0.4) to 0?

Tags: c

I'm writhing this code and I need to split 2/5(0.4) to could continue with the another operations. The problem is that when I get the output, instead of getting 0.4, C automatically approximates it to 0.00000.
What can I do to avoid C rounding 0.4 to 5?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    double valor_a_depreciar=150000;
    int anos_depreciacion=5;
    double valor_final_depreciado;
    int cont_p3= 1;
    double acu_saldo;
    double acu_p3;
        for(cont_p3; cont_p3<=anos_depreciacion; cont_p3++)
        {
            valor_final_depreciado= valor_a_depreciar*(2/anos_depreciacion);
            printf("Ano %d: %lf\n", cont_p3, valor_final_depreciado);
            valor_a_depreciar= valor_a_depreciar - valor_final_depreciado;
            acu_p3= acu_p3+valor_final_depreciado;
        }
        printf("El producto se deprecio $ %lf en %d anos\n",acu_p3, anos_depreciacion);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: double a=2, b=5, d= 2/5; If I print d, although the result is 0.4, C automatically approximates it to 0.0000 :(

Comment: Use `(2.0 / anos_depreciacion )` to get floating point division instead of integer division.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I've trying to find an answers for that for around half an hour and I never expect to my error was that silly. <3

Comment: If this is going to be expanded into something more, BE SURE to check that the denominator is never 0. Dividing by zero is impossible.